# Can a MacBook Pro13-inc, 2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i7 use CL9 memory reliably?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, performance

Looking for a memory upgrade for a macbook pro 13-inc, 2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i7, The Apple specifications call for CL11 RAM.

The question is if it will work fine with a CL9 memory so I can take advantage of [benchmark improvements like this](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ram-throw-down-cl9-vs-cl11.1559336/)?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't risk buying something that is not explicitly supported. You may want to check http://www.corsair.com/en-us/corsair-mac-memory-16gb-dual-channel-ddr3-sodimm-memory-kit-cmsa16gx3m2a1600c11, which, as Corsair states: "Corsair's Mac memory kits are tested at Apple Developer Compatibility Labs and work with most MacBook® Pro, iMac®, and Mac mini systems shipped in 2011 and newer." I bought 16 GB for my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) and works like a charm. (I'm in no way affiliated to Corsair...)

Comment: @jaume That comment is good enough to serve as an answer. It has great practical use even if some people don't want the answer to just run with what's supported by either Apple or the 3PP vendor.

Comment: @bmike Thanks, I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't risk buying anything that is not explicitly supported. You may run into problems in the long term if the memory modules draw too much power or are too fast/slow.

You may want to check [corsair.com/en-us/…](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/corsair-mac-memory-16gb-dual-channel-ddr3-sodimm-memory-kit-cmsa16gx3m2a1600c11), a 2x8GB memory module pack with 11-11-11-30 [CAS timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings) (that is, CL=11, as Apple recommends). Corsair states that their "memory kits are tested at Apple Developer Compatibility Labs and work with most MacBook® Pro, iMac®, and Mac mini systems shipped in 2011 and newer."

Since you mention in a comment that you plan on installing 16 GB while Apple only officially supports 8 GB: I bought [16 GB](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/corsair-mac-memory-16gb-dual-channel-ddr3-sodimm-memory-kit-cmsa16gx3m2a1333c9) for my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) and it works like a charm, although Apple's documentation states the maximum installable memory is 8 GB.

Since my Mac has a non supported configuration, if I go to a Genius Appointment in an Apple Store I consequently replace my non-stardard modules with the original ones.

**To summarize:**

- Stick to Apple's specs (speed, type, voltage, format, etc).
- If other people confirm that more than the supported amount of RAM works, it is definitely worth a try. It will either work or fail, but it won't burn your computer's motherboard of anything. See this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/73730/i-want-to-install-more-than-the-supported-amount-of-ram-on-my-pc-is-it-likely-t) at superuser for some opinions on this topic.

(Disclamer: I'm in no way affiliated to Corsair.)

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside any concerns that you won't realize much gain - just buy the RAM from a vendor that will back up the use you intend and/or offer pre-sales assistance to ensure you don't need to return product that works fine but is installed in the wrong Mac.

I can't vouch for that particular model, but the Mac logic boards are now easily identified by GPU/CPU and you can trust that any RAM that works when reviewed by any PC or Mac site will work for you on your CPU.

Hopefully someone will have actual experience if you can't get assistance from the vendor and extrapolating from other customer reviews online.

Comment: My concern is that however apple suggests max 8GB RAM 16 GB works fine, everyone confirms it. So I believe it should be the same with a CL9 RAM as well which gives a significant performance increase (however people do not conform that a lower CL gives it, I know it by experience). So trying to find someone with real life experience for this particular mac version befor spending money). Thanks.